# Trivial manipulation of nonconvergent series validity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, notation

I know that the harmonic series diverges
$$H=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}+...\rightarrow Diverges$$

Hence, I know that if all the terms of the harmonic series are made negative, that series also diverges
$$h=-\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}-...-\frac{1}{n}+...$$

But can I write:
$$h=-H$$
or is there some notation to indicate this.

I am not trying to create new maths. I am asking what is the correct notation to indicate that one series is obtained from the other by making each term negative.

Comment: I would say that you cannot write something like that. The reason is that if you do, you may start believing that the usual rules of arithmetic still apply. A standard example of what may go wrong is to name
$$S=1-1+1-1+1-1+1-\cdots,$$
and then to think that we can still calculate
$$1-S=1-(1-1+1-1+\cdots)=1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots=S,$$
and then "solve for $S$" from the resulting equation $S=1-S$ to conclude $S=1/2$. The moral: *Beware of naming things that don't necessarily exist!*

Comment: So then what is the correct way to indicate this fact? Just say it verbally.....That is very lengthy.

Comment: Many textbooks do state (and prove) a result that if a series $\sum_{n}a_n$ diverges, and $c$ is a non-zero constant, then the series $\sum_n ca_n$ diverges also. It may happen that only the case of convergent series is included, because A) we can actually use convergent series for calculations, and B) then we don't need to add a special clause to cover the case $c=0$.

Comment: Without the knowledge that such a series is divergent, it is alright to write this as part of a proof by contradiction. But once this fact is known, you should not write negatives as per the reasoning above.

Comment: If $H$ is a convergent series, then you can certainly indicate that $h$ is obtained from $H$ by negating every term by writing $h=-H$. But if $H$ is divergent, then I don't think there's anything you can do other than write, "$h=-H$, where what I mean by $-H$ is the series you get by negating every term in $H$".

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise, you could prove "if any series converges with a limit L, then the same series with all elements multiplied by the same real number c converges to c*L". You can also prove "If any series converges with a limit L, and another converges with a limit L', then the series created by adding the elements converges with a limit L + L'".

That's assuming the limit is not +/- infinity. In that case a series multiplied by 0 converges to 0, while 0 times +/- infinity is not defined. And adding two series with limits +infinity and -infinity may or may not converge, and if it converges, the limit might be anything.

Your example is the first case with c = -1.